# AWS S3 giving different versions of file for visual hosted style and path style URL

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, carrierwave

I have a rails application that use carrier-wave to upload file to S3. So after uploading a file through attachmentuploader. I am saving public url for given object in database. Public url returned by `aws-sdk ruby gem` is in **visual-hosted-style**

`https://BUCKETNAME.s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/tests/TESTNAME.zip`

If I check object url in s3 it is in **path style** format -

`https://s3.REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKETNAME/tests/TESTNAME.zip`

Docs regarding [url style](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html)

The problem here is that, if I access public url that is stored in my db after updating assets it points to previous version instead of latest version as done by object_url. So why public url is not updating to latest version and this issue came up 2 days before. Any insight will be helpful

**UPDATE**

Now this issue is resolved automatically. So if someone faced this issue or have any understanding. Please let me know

Comment: did you try deleting the s3 object before creating one in the same name

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser cache to see whether it is the cause? If so, then you can change some metadata that tells the browser how long to cache an object.

Comment: i am hitting the url with okhttp:3.11 from android application. This isn't the case